# I can't install wine32 because of unmet dependencies that are packages I already installed

Tags: apt, wine, dependencies

I want to install wine32, but for whatever reason this shows up:

```
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 apt : Depends: adduser but it is not going to be installed
       Recommends: ca-certificates but it is not going to be installed
 init : PreDepends: systemd-sysv
 libkf5pulseaudioqt3 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.15.0~) but it is not going 
to be installed or
                                libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.15.0~) but it is not 
going to be installed
 login : PreDepends: libpam-runtime but it is not going to be installed
         PreDepends: libpam-modules but it is not going to be installed
 pdftk-java : Depends: default-jre-headless but it is not going to be 
installed or
                       java8-runtime-headless
 qt5-image-formats-plugins : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.15.3+dfsg~) but it is 
not going to be installed or
                                      libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.15.3+dfsg~) but 
it is not going to be installed
 shim-signed : Depends: mokutil (>= 0.3.0+1538710437.fb6250f-0ubuntu2) but it 
is not going to be installed
               Depends: sbsigntool but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: secureboot-db but it is not going to be installed
```

I have installed these packages but this is still showing. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you launch this command before installing wine?
'sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386'

Comment: No, I added i386 before doing that @Wingarmac

Comment: Then I presume you'll have to purge and reinstall following the instruction below.
I've had to do that with the same issue to solve it. You're using a 64 bit system and no 32 bit libraries are installed by default. These are installed if you specify to implement the 32 bit environment with `sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386`before reinstall  @etcetera

Comment: Can you add the release used `lsb_release -d` ? Are you using the proprietary drivers and are those up to date ? Did you try to reinstall wine after checking these ? What's the output of `wine --version` ? @Etcetera

Answer (score 0):

Install aptitude (installs by checking and prompt to install unmet dependencies):

```
sudo apt install aptitude
```

Use it instead of **apt install** if needed to met dependencies you don't have identified yet. Use it also to check for updates:

```
sudo aptitude update
```

If you still have trouble after that, purge your current installation of wine with the command:

```
sudo aptitude purge wine
```

Before reinstalling wine, you need to know your Ubuntu release version.Ubuntu is providing wine-stable on it's default repos.
If you prefer to use the last versions of wine, you'll have to add there repos and install the wanted version (stable-development-staging) like explained on [WineHQ](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu) depending on your distro.